# Git and working on multiple branches

Tags: git, version-control, branch

I have a couple of Git branches: 'experimental', 'something' and 'master'.

I switched to the 'experimental' branch. I noticed a bug which is unrelated to 'experimental' and belongs to changes which have been made in 'something'. How should I fix it?

I'm thinking I should switch to 'something', fix the bug, commit and then move back to 'experimental'. How should I take the minor change from 'something' and apply it to both 'master' and 'experimental' so that I don't have to re-fix the bug again when I switch into these branches?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There are two solutions not mentioned already that you can use: use a **topic branch** or use **cherry-picking**.

---

#### Topic branch solution

In the **topic branch solution**, you switch to branch 'something', *create a branch to fix a bug* e.g. 'something-bugfix', merge this branch into 'something' (fixing the bug), then merge this branch into 'experimental'.

```
$ git checkout -b something-fix something
[edit, commit]
$ git checkout something
$ git merge something-fix
$ git checkout experimental
$ git merge something-fix
[fix conflicts if necessary and commit]
```

See also [Resolving conflicts/dependencies between topic branches early](http://gitster.livejournal.com/27297.html) and [Never merging back](http://gitster.livejournal.com/26540.html), and perhaps also [Committing to a different branch](http://gitster.livejournal.com/25892.html) blog posts by Junio C Hamano (git maintainer).

---

#### Cherry-picking a bugfix

The **cherry-picking** solution is useful if you noticed *later* that the bugfix you created (e.g. on development branch) would be useful also on other branch (e.g. stable branch). In your case you would comit a fix on 'something' branch:

```
$ git checkout something
[edit, edit, edit]
$ git commit
$ git checkout experimental
```

Then you noticed that fix you comitted in 'something' branch should be also on 'experimenta' branch.  Lets say that this bugfix was commit 'A' (e.g. 'something' if you didn't commit anything on top of 'something', but it might be e.g. 'something~2' or 'c84fb911'):

```
$ git checkout experimental
$ git cherry-pick A
```

(you can use `--edit` option to [git cherry-pick](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) if you want to edit commit message before comitting cherry-picked bugfix).

Answer (score 5):

you could:

- `stash` or `commit` the changes you have been working on the `experimental` branch
- `checkout something`
- (optional) `bisect` to find the bug
- `commit` the changes
- `checkout experimental`

and then:

- `rebase something` if you want a clean commit graph (if you expose this repository and you care about that)

or:

- `merge something` if you don't care about 'presentation' :)

Answer (score 2):

since your **experimental** branch has features from **something** you should do one of the:

- merge **something** into **experimental** after you fix the bug there.
- rebase your **experimental** on top of **something**

Comment: +1: I switched to the branch that contained the fix, committed it, then rebased to master on all the other branches; now all the branches contain the fix. This is the desired outcome. Thanks!

Comment: be aware that rebasing is troublesome for other people if they are pulling from your repository

Answer (score 0):

If you don't progress in 'master' too much, just switch back to the experimental and do 'git merge master'. If you do, I think the 'git cherry-pick' command is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Your branches are somehow related like this:

master > something > experimental

This is, if you really intend to merge something into master.

I would if possible, fix it on top of master, then rebase the others on top of master. But I simply like rebasing. Or you could fix it there and then merge exactly like that

master > something > experimental

but if something is a simple topic branch, I would not do that. Here it sounds like something is your "candidate next master"

Answer (score 0):

If you can merge, then do so.  If you don't want to merge **something** into the other branches, then fix the bug and cherry-pick that commit into each of the other branches.

Answer (score 0):

Git worktrees allow you to work on multiple branches simultaneously without re-cloning. Use git worktree add to create a new worktree, enabling efficient branch switching for different tasks.

#### 1. **Navigate to Your Project:**

- Open Git Bash and go to your project's directory. For example:

  ```bash
  cd /path/to/your/project
  ```

#### 2. **Create a New Worktree:**

- Use the `git worktree add` command to create a new worktree. For instance, if your project is in C:\projects\the_project and you want to create a new worktree at C:\projects\the_project_2 for a branch named "feature_branch," use:

  ```bash
  git worktree add ../the_project_2 feature_branch
  ```
- This creates a new directory "the_project_2" and checks out the "feature_branch" into it.

#### 3. **Open Visual Studio with the New Worktree:**

- Open Visual Studio and choose the new folder (the_project_2) as your project directory.
- You can now work on the "feature_branch" in this new worktree.

#### 4. **Switching Between Worktrees:**

- You can easily switch between different worktrees by using standard Git commands. For example, to switch back to the original worktree:

  ```bash
  cd /path/to/your/project
  ```

#### 5. **Managing Worktrees:**

- To list your existing worktrees:

  ```bash
  git worktree list
  ```
- To remove a worktree (be cautious not to lose important changes):

  ```bash
  git worktree remove ../the_project_2
  ```

#### 6. **Benefit: No Re-Cloning Needed:**

- Unlike before, you don't have to clone the entire project again just to switch branches.

#### 7. **Note for Older Visual Studio Versions:**

- Some older versions of Visual Studio might not fully support this feature.

Remember to replace "/path/to/your/project," "feature_branch," and "../the_project_2" with your actual project path, branch name, and desired worktree path. This approach allows you to work on different branches simultaneously without the need for redundant cloning.

> For more information can refer the link:
> https://www.gitkraken.com/learn/git/git-worktree